# const Generic type parameter not inferred as const when using conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Typescript allows a `const` modifier on function type parameters so that the inferred type is the same as if the received literal had `as const`

```
function identity<const T>(a: T){ 
  return a
}
```

when using `identity({ a: 42 })` the inferred type is `{ a: 42 }` not `{ a: number }` which is expected. The weird behavior happens in the following:

```
function optionalIfFoo<
   K extends string, 
   const T
>(foo: K, ...rest: K extends 'foo' ? []: [bar: T]){
   return rest[0]
}
```

Works as expected except for the inference of T. The inferred type of T in `optionalIfFoo('notFoo', { a: 42 })` is `{ a: number }` instead of `{ a: 42 }`

Is there a way to make it infer `{ a: 42 }` in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that [`const` type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) don't always work together with the other "tricks" I'd normally use to guide type inference.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#53813](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53813) for instance.

I can't pretend to know exactly how it works.  My general approach is to make things as easy as possible for the compiler to infer as we intend.  Given your code example here I'd probably refactor to a version like this:

```
function optionalIfFoo<
    K extends string,
    const U extends (K extends "foo" ? readonly [] : readonly [unknown])
>(foo: K, ...rest: U): U[0] {
    return rest[0]
}
```

Here I've got `U` playing the role of your `[T]`, more or less, so to get `T` out of it we'd write `U[0]`.  I've moved the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) from the `rest` parameter type to a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `U`.  And it uses  [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) so that the `const` type parameter will work (this is an important caveat; mutable constraints tend to do weird things).

Anyway, now `rest` can be of type `U`, a bare type parameter, which is usually the optimal way to infer a type argument, since it represents the least amount of work for the compiler.  In other words, inferring `T` from a value of type `K extends 'foo' ? []: [bar: T]` might or might not be possible, but inferring `U` from a value of type `U` really should be straightforward.

Let's see if it works:

```
const v = optionalIfFoo('notFoo', { a: 42 });
// K: "notFoo", U: readonly [{ readonly a: 42; }]
// const v: { readonly a: 42; } 

const w = optionalIfFoo('foo'); 
// K: "foo", U: readonly []
// const w: undefined
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers `U` in the expected `const` way, and therefore the return type is also as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHADrBBDANgSWAMTjgB4AoRCxAaUQFMAPKWsAEwGdE2oAnGMAcwA05ShARdEAVTqNm7RAAoaDJqw4AiYEXWIA-Im60MLBFgCeiANoBdRAC4DRk2HNXwAazBwA7mGsBKUgA+BS04BypBRAA6WMMuB0l-RMsABlsAbxEKQygQbiR4qDTrUgBfUlIxMAkAN0QAXmQ0eDBsPEI4BQByLyhO7qiMxAwHABYAJkQy-wBuUgB6BeoHdT7O9SjJB0NjUwtLYd3nV1HESdnp0qXEarqHI6d9kfGJy7LEKvEoRG9G5vQbVwBCIPTC3TmnxuVFWYU2Uh2TxcB2uyzuP28DnALFowD4tBYnyAA)